# How to pass the parameter from one action to other

Tags: struts2

hi I am new in Struts2 and want to send parameter from one action to other on redirection

My form is like

```
<s:form action="saveComment">
                            <s:push value="ai">
                                <s:hidden name="id"/>
                                <table cellpadding="5px">
                                    <tr><td><s:textarea name="description" rows="5" cols="60" theme="simple" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td> <s:submit type="image" src="images/sbt.gif"  >
                                             </s:submit>
                                        </td></tr>

                                </table>
                            </s:push>
                        </s:form>
```

and my struts.xml file is  like

```
 <action name="saveComment" method="saveComment" class="com.weaverants.web.AIAction">

        <result name="success" type="redirect">
            <param name="actionName">displayAI</param>
            <param name="aiId">${aiId}</param>
        </result>

    </action>


   <action name="displayAI" method="displayAI"  class="com.weaverants.web.AIAction">
        <result name="success" >/display_ai.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

Comment: I see your answer has been posted. I would just like to say consider using some form of DI such as Spring along with the very easy to use struts2-conventions-plugin.  What this will do is largely remove your xml configuration, and your application flow will be easily understood in java.  As it stands you have flow control (rather than just definitions) defined in xml. Long story short chaining, redirecting, forwarding is like goto. As the exception it's okay, as the rule a nightmare.

Comment: @Quaternion: fully agree what you said.good way to go +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already passing the parameters in your `saveComment` all you need to declare result type as `redirectAction` specifying the `action` name as the redirectAction and any other needed parameters. like

```
<action name="gatherReportInfo" class="...">
      <result name="showReportResult" type="redirectAction">
         <param name="actionName">generateReport</param>
         <param name="namespace">/genReport</param>
         <param name="reportType">pie</param>
         <param name="width">100</param>
         <param name="height">100</param>
         <param name="empty"></param>

      </result>
   </action>
```

the redirected URL generated will be

```
 /genReport/generateReport.action?reportType=pie&width=100&height=100
```

On the other hand using result type as `redirect` means response is told to redirect the browser to the specified location (a new request from the client).In this case also action instance, action errors, field errors, etc that was just executed is lost and no longer available and only way to pass parameters is by URL or through session

Same code as stated for redirectAction can be used

difference between Redirect and actionRedirect is the the first one will use `HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect(String) sendRedirect` while the later one will be taken care by the struts2 framework by ActionMapper provided by the ActionMapperFactory as is much better to use than  `Redirect` result.

For passing data beside the URL pattern for these result type you can use

1. Session to persist data between Action redirect.
2. [ScopeInterceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/ScopeInterceptor.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using the [chain result](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=struts2%20chain%20result&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11/docs/chain-result.html&ei=lqIbT6HwFI6zrAeIq6HLDQ&usg=AFQjCNEUprirRwCT2IOGHwS4baf2d46r5Q) instead of `redirectAction` .All the parameters from first action will be passed to the second action but you do need to have the getters and setters of parameters in the second action. It would look something like this:

```
<result type="chain">
<param name="actionName">home</param>
<param name="namespace">/secure</param>
</result>
```

Comment: unfortunately chain result have so many negative sides and even the official documents say this.So until you have a pressing reason to use it ,avoid this. [chaining](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/action-chaining.html)